# MS Access 2013 saved exports not saving to MSysIMEXSpecs table

Tags: ms-access, export

I am working on an Access 2013 database that someone else created.  It has a module that exports several reports as PDF files to a specific folder.  Some of the reports are exporting successfully but 3 of them aren't.  An example of the code used is as follows:
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-rptJobsToClose_FS2"

I receive an error that the database can't save the output data to the file you've selected.  I realize that the path is saved in the "Export-rptJobsToClose_FS2" saved export. I would like to see the path so I have tried opening the MSysIMEXSpecs table but when I do, it is totally empty.  So is the corresponding table MSysIMEXColumns.  If I create a new SavedExport definition and use the same name as the one in the code, I get the message that it already exists.  How is that possible that it already exists when those system tables are empty?  I have tried creating saved exports with new names, but if they don't work I can't reuse those names as I get the message that they already exist.  So, I have to keep thinking of new names and can't see any information about the Saved Exports that I have already created.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

MSysIMEX* tables contain import specifications for correct data transfer. Saved import-exports stored in other place. You can see all names of saved imports/exports using menu External Data -> Saved Imports/Exports, there you can also see and edit destination path and import/export name.

Thru VBA you can reach the collection of saved imports/exports by using collection `CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications`, destination path stored in `XML` attribute of each `Item`.

The code below prints all existing import-export specifications

```
Dim ie As ImportExportSpecification

For Each ie In CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
    Debug.Print ie.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Part of my problem is that I see nothing listed in the Manage Data Tasks window which comes up when you go to External data ->Saved Imports/Exports for either exports or imports.  You said the saved import-exports are stored in another place.  Can you tell me where that is?  I have created some VBA code to try to loop through the ImportExportSpecifications collections.  I used debug.print to print the name and XML to the immediate window but so far, I see only import specifications.

Comment: Specifications saved in internal database structures, you cannot see it in tables. I added the code, which allows to see all specifications. It it doesn't print some specifications, you don't see them in the Data Tasks window, but cannot create new specification with the same name, it may mean that the database corrupted, try to run compact&restore first.

Answer (score 1):

Saved import/exports in Access are not the same thing as import/export specifications. If you want to see the saved import/export definition, you can dump it by typing the following command into the Immediate window.

```
? CodeProject.ImportExportSpecifications(*SpecificationName*).XML
```